# Get list elements between startdate and enddate python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

the python list is as below:

```
[('TimeCreated : 2020/07/08 8:38:36', ' ソース ネットワーク アドレス: 172.16.1.1')]
[('TimeCreated : 2020/07/07 13:12:18', ' ソース ネットワーク アドレス: 172.16.1.1')]
[('TimeCreated : 2020/07/07 8:42:22', ' ソース ネットワーク アドレス: 172.16.1.1')]
[('TimeCreated : 2020/07/06 16:06:40', ' ソース ネットワーク アドレス: 172.16.1.1')]
```

I need to get the elements between startdate(2020/07/07 8:00:00) and enddate(2020/07/08 17:30:00) then how can i fetch:

python code is as below:

```
for s in t:                      
    _date = datetime.strptime(s[0], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    if start_dt <= _date and _date <= end_dt:
     intime.append([_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] + s[1:])
```

but it shown me error:

```
ValueError: time data 'TimeCreated : 2020/07/08 8:38:36' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget that the time string is actually `'TimeCreated : 2020/07/08 8:38:36'` which is of course invalid. You can split it on `' : '` and use the second part:

```
for s in t:                      
    _date = datetime.strptime(s[0].split(' : ')[1], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    if start_dt <= _date and _date <= end_dt:
        intime.append([_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] + s[1:])
```

Following the comment made below: it is also possible to include the prefix in the formatter:

```
for s in t:                      
    _date = datetime.strptime(s[0], 'TimeCreated : %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    if start_dt <= _date and _date <= end_dt:
        intime.append([_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] + s[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `TimeCreated :` from `s[0]`

```
_date = datetime.strptime(s[0].replace("TimeCreated : ", ""), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The error occurs because of 'TimeCreated : 2020/07/08 8:38:36' string is not a datetime format by replacing `'TimeCreated :'` with `""` will make the string a valid datetime format.